# Oracle: Error ORA-00932: inconsistent Datatypes number assumed, but got ARRAY

Tags: oracle

We are trying to select an array/varray type with embedded SQL.

Type/Table:

```
create type int55 is array(4) of integer;
create table rtable (a int, b int55);
```

Code for SQL Precompiler in C++ with Oracle 11g Client:

```
BOOL static_TestIt(void) {
  EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    int a;
    long b[4];
    short i[4];
  EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

  EXEC SQL DECLARE cdtest_cursor CURSOR FOR select a,b from rtable;
  EXEC SQL open cdtest_cursor;
  EXEC SQL FETCH cdtest_cursor INTO  :a, :b:i;
  EXEC SQL close cdtest_cursor; 

  return TRUE; 
}
```

The precompiler shows warning:
PCC-W-02344 invalid size of host array

During runtime i get error: ORA-00932

Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a few more steps, based on the documentation on [collection handling in Pro*C](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpcc/about-Collections.html).

First, create a file called `int55_in.typ` containing the name of your collection type:

```
case=lower
type int55
```

Then run [the object type translator tool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpcc/the-Object-type.html):

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/ott intype=int55_in.typ outtype=int55_out.typ hfile=int55.h user=usr/pwd code=c
```

which will generate two files. In your `.pc` file add:

```
#include "int55.h"
```

and your code needs to use that declared collection type:

```
  EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    int a;
    int55 *b;   /* collection type */
    int c;      /* single instance from collection */
    OCIInd i;   /* indicator */
  EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

  EXEC SQL ALLOCATE :b;

  EXEC SQL DECLARE cdtest_cursor CURSOR FOR select a, b from rtable;
  EXEC SQL open cdtest_cursor;
  EXEC SQL FETCH cdtest_cursor INTO :a, :b:i;
```

Then you can use `COLLECTION GET` to get the individual elements; as it's a varray you can loop over the four entries, e.g. as a simple demo:

```
  int j;
  for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
    EXEC SQL COLLECTION GET :b INTO :c;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", j, a, c);
  }

  EXEC SQL close cdtest_cursor;
```

When you compile you need tomake sure the location for `oci.h` (included from the generated `int55.h`) if it isn't already referred to; and you need to specify the generated type file:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/proc include=$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/public intyp=int55_out.typ ...
```

With a single row in your table:

```
insert into rtable values (1, int55(2, 3, 4, 5));
```

running that then gets:

```
0 1 2
1 1 3
2 1 4
3 1 5
```

Obviously you should pick your own file names, I've just used your type name as an example to hopefully make it clearer. And if you have to handle mutlipel types they can all go in a single `_in.typ` to generate a single _out.typ`and`.h` file.